# How to call reducer action without redux saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have redux saga in my project, but I would like to call reducer action directly from my component.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  showUsers: () => dispatch(UserActions.showUsers()),
})
```

It works fine if showUsers is inside saga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` can be a simple object with the action inside

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  showUsers: UserActions.showUsers,
};
```

then you can pass it to `connect`. `connect` will call `dispatch` internally

`connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)`

then inside your component, you can call your action

`this.props.showUsers()`

[More info about the different forms of mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops)